# 406 Error / Response with Eventbrite Search API

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, eventbrite

I am currently trying to pull data from the Eventbrite API platform in Jupyter Labs. Sporadically, I am receiving a 406 Not Acceptable Error when I make the request. However, invariably, if I make the same request again a few minutes later the request pulls the data fine.

I've checked the usual things: ie that I have not gone over my request limits.

Here is the request I am currently making:

```
url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?token=MY_TOKEN_HERE&location.latitude=42.34631505453378&location.longitude=-71.04174243961083&location.within=3km&start_date.range_start=2019-10-30T00:00:00Z&start_date.range_end=2019-11-30T00:00:00Z&expand=venue'

x = requests.get(url)
x
```

And the response:

```
<Response [406]>
```

Any thoughts on what the problem might be?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it seems to come and go. This may be a good time to report the error to Eventbrite. I'm sure they'll appreciate a proactive API consumer.

Comment: Yeah me too. I don't know how to issue requests for each page in the response (using pagination) because it's rate limiting us pretty hard. I think this has just started happening to my app and now I can't deploy the backend. :( has anyone found a fix for this?

Comment: has anyone found solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I got an email from them a little over a week ago saying:

*Hello,
We're reaching out today to follow up regarding the events/search/ endpoint. Thank you for your patience while we worked to reach a conclusion to the issue.
Access to the Eventbrite Event Search API (GET /v3/events/search/) will be shut down at 11:59 pm PT on Thursday, December 12, 2019.*

*We strongly encourage you to find and remove any code that makes requests to this Event Search API from your applications in advance.*

**Why is this happening?**
*We’re removing the Event Search API to further improve the Eventbrite platform and allow us to support more Creators and their events. Allowing public access to this particular API was impacting our platform and the high level of service we strive to provide to our creators and their attendees. We are able to provide alternative access to retrieve your event data through our Event APIs (see below).*

**What is the replacement API?**
*To get Events via our API, please see: 
    •   Retrieve an Event by ID — GET /v3/events/:event_id/
    •   List Events by Venue — GET /v3/venues/:venue_id/events/ 
    •   List Events by Organization — GET /v3/organizations/:organization_id/events/*

*If you’re retrieving private events on behalf of another user, you can complete the app authorization flow. If you’re interested in retrieving public events on behalf of many Eventbrite creators, you can apply to our distribution partner program.*

*We apologize for the delay in communication regarding this decision, as well as for the inconvenience and frustration this change has caused*

*Regards,
Eventbrite Developer Support*

So it looks like that's finally confirmed as dead at least.

Answer (score 0):

FYI... this is an an ongoing Eventbrite API issue that is causing problems for many. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eventbrite-api/-E0MG7THMsc